# How to implement the Elvis operator in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

I have the classic "Elvis operator" case, where I'm calling methods that each may return null and chaining them together:

```
thing?:nullableMethod1(a)?:nullableMethod2(b)?:nullableMethod3()
```

In Java 8, the most faithful implementation I've found is something like this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(thing)
    .flatMap(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.nullableMethod1(a)))
    .flatMap(y -> Optional.ofNullable(y.nullableMethod2(b)))
    .flatMap(z -> Optional.ofNullable(z.nullableMethod3()))
```

I wish that Java's `Optional` had something akin to the elvis operator:

```
public<U> Optional<U> elvisOperator(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    return flatMap(t -> Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(t));
}
```

So that I wouldn't have to wrap each return value:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(thing)
    .elvisOperator(x -> x.nullableMethod1(a))
    .elvisOperator(y -> y.nullableMethod2(b))
    .elvisOperator(Z::nullableMethod3); // also nice
```

Is there a more efficient and idiomatic way to implement the Elvis operator pattern in Java 8?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but is there a reason that you can't use `Optional#map`?

The following example prints nothing, as `Optional` is *short-circuiting* in the sense that, if the value inside the `Optional` doesn't exist (it's `null` or the `Optional` is empty), it's treated as empty.

```
Optional.ofNullable("test")
        .map(s -> null)
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

For that reason, I'd think you could just do the following:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(thing)
               .map(x -> x.nullableMethod1(a))
               .map(y -> y.nullableMethod2(b))
               .map(Z::nullableMethod3);
```

This would map your `thing` if it exists, or return an empty `Optional` otherwise.

Comment: It’s worth pointing to [the documentation of `Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) to show that the behavior is intentional: “*If the mapping function returns a `null` result then this method returns an empty `Optional`*”.

Comment: @Holger, and [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/optional-broken/) explains why, in the long run, that was a bad idea.  Or, at least, sub-optimal (from a FP perspective).

Comment: They implemented a very important feature but for some reason decided to severely damage trusty old map in the process. It would be easier to forgive if they had actually named the necessary second method with this behavior "elvis" 

Answer (score 14):

In Java 8, the Elvis operator can be simulated by chaining `.map(...)` calls on an `Optional.ofNullable(...)` and capping it with `.orElse(...)`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(dataObject)
.map(DataObject::getNestedDataObject)
.map(NestedDataObject::getEvenMoreNestedDataObject)
...
.orElse(null);
```

A full example:

```java
import java.util.Optional;

class Main {
  // Data classes:
  static class Animal {
    Leg leg;

    Animal(Leg leg) {
      this.leg = leg;
    }

    Leg getLeg(){return this.leg;}

    public String toString(){
      String out = "This is an animal";
      out += leg != null ? " with a leg" : "";
      return out;
    }
  }

  static class Leg {
    Toes toes;

    Leg(Toes toes) {
      this.toes = toes;
    }

    Toes getToes(){return this.toes;}

    public String toString(){
      String out = "This is a leg";
      out += toes != null ? " with a collection of toes" : "";
      return out;
    }
  }

  static class Toes {
    Integer numToes;

    Toes(Integer numToes) {
      this.numToes = numToes;
    }

    Integer getNumToes(){return this.numToes;}

    public String toString(){
      String out = "This is a collection of ";
      out += numToes != null && numToes > 0 ? numToes : "no";
      out += " toes";
      return out;
    }
  }

  // A few example Elvis operators:
  static Integer getNumToesOrNull(Animal a) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(a)
      .map(Animal::getLeg)
      .map(Leg::getToes)
      .map(Toes::getNumToes)
      .orElse(null);
  }

  static Toes getToesOrNull(Animal a) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(a)
      .map(Animal::getLeg)
      .map(Leg::getToes)
      .orElse(null);
  }

  static Leg getLegOrNull(Animal a) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(a)
      .map(Animal::getLeg)
      .orElse(null);
  }

  // Main function:
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Trying to access 'numToes':
    System.out.println(getNumToesOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(new Toes(4))))); // 4
    System.out.println(getNumToesOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(new Toes(null))))); // null
    System.out.println(getNumToesOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(null)))); // null
    System.out.println(getNumToesOrNull(new Animal(null))); // null
    System.out.println(getNumToesOrNull(null)); // null

    // Trying to access 'toes':
    System.out.println(getToesOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(new Toes(4))))); // This is a collection of 4 toes
    System.out.println(getToesOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(new Toes(null))))); // This is a collection of no toes
    System.out.println(getToesOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(null)))); // null
    System.out.println(getToesOrNull(new Animal(null))); // null
    System.out.println(getToesOrNull(null)); // null

    // Trying to access 'leg':
    System.out.println(getLegOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(new Toes(4))))); // This is a leg with a collection of toes
    System.out.println(getLegOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(new Toes(null))))); // This is a leg with a collection of toes
    System.out.println(getLegOrNull(new Animal(new Leg(null)))); // This is a leg
    System.out.println(getLegOrNull(new Animal(null))); // null
    System.out.println(getLegOrNull(null)); // null
  }
}
```

Comment: I think what you're adding to the accepted answer is that some languages blur the concepts of optionality and nullability in such a way that the Elvis operator can be used without needing to unpack the result at the end.  In Java, the method implementations sometimes blur those concepts, but the type system has distinct notions, so yes, you're right that if one wanted a @Nullable Foo instead of an Optional<Foo>, one would likely want to use orElse at the end.

Comment: @Mickalot yes, that was the point I was trying to make. I had seen a few other answers and was confused by how to do it without an `Optional`, until I tried this example. I thought it might benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

There is one [compiler plugin](https://github.com/vinayalodha/elvis) I have written which manipulate AST to generate `Optional.ofNullable` chain in compile time

It has few limitations but it does reduce repetitive code

PS: I am author of plugin

Answer (score 0):

To complete a bit Jacob's idea, I created this class:

```
public class OptionalUtils {
  public static <T, U> Optional<U> elvisOperator(T t, Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    return elvisOperator(Optional.ofNullable(t), mapper);
  }

  public static <T, U> Optional<U> elvisOperator(Optional<T> optional, Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    return optional.flatMap(t -> Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(t)));
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
elvisOperator(elvisOperator(dataObject, DataObject::getNestedDataObject)
    NestedDataObject::getEvenMoreNestedDataObject))...
```

Another Fluent approach:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.Optional;

public class OptionalChaining<T> {
  private final Optional<T> t;

  public OptionalChaining(T t) {
    this.t=Optional.ofNullable(t);
  }
  public OptionalChaining(Optional<T> t) {
    this.t=t;
  }
  public <U> OptionalChaining<U> get(Function<T, U> function) {
    return new OptionalChaining(this.t
        .flatMap(e -> Optional.ofNullable(function.apply(e))));
  }
  public Optional<T> get() {
    return t;
  }
}
```

We can then write this:

```
new OptionalChaining<>(dataObject)
    .get(DataObject::getNestedDataObject)
    .get(NestedDataObject::getEvenMoreNestedDataObject)
    .get()
```

I am so frustrated to not find this in a common Java Library (such as Guava, Langs, Vavr, ...). The only way seems to use the "or" operator on Stream but I find it so verbose :-(

Answer (score -1):

Another option to simulate the elvis operator would be using following helper function:

```
public static <T> T get(final Supplier<T> it) {
    try {
        return it.get();
    } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You could use it like:

```
var x = get(() -> thing.nullableMethod1(a).nullableMethod2(b).nullableMethod3());
```

Comment: Actually not that stupid! However cannot distinguish between a NPE raised by the getter, or raised by the result :-(